# iOS UIWebView leaked

Tags: ios, webview, uiwebview

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
     @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView?
     override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
    SVProgressHUD.show()

    webView?.loadRequest(request)
    webView?.scrollView.header = MJRefreshNormalHeader(refreshingBlock: {

      [weak self] in
      if let strongSelf = self {
        strongSelf.webView?.reload()
      }})   }
     override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated) 

    SVProgressHUD.dismiss()   }    }

extension MyViewController: UIWebViewDelegate {
     func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
    webView.scrollView.header.endRefreshing()
    SVProgressHUD.dismiss()   }       func webView(webView: UIWebView, didFailLoadWithError error: NSError?) {
    webView.scrollView.header.endRefreshing()
    SVProgressHUD.dismiss()   }    }
```

The view controller was pushed by a navigation controller, when I pop it, I got leaks. In instrument.Leak I saw these.

### #

```
Leaked Object   #   Address Size    Responsible Library Responsible Frame NSMutableArray    1   0x137a6ddb0 48 Bytes    UIKit   -[_UIKeyboardTextSelectionGestureController init]
_UIKeyboardTextSelectionController  1   0x137a6e800 96 Bytes    UIKit   -[UIWebSelectionAssistant addNonEditableForceTextSelectionGestureRecognizersToView:]
_UIKeyboardBasedNonEditableTextSelectionGestureController   1   0x137a6dcd0 160 Bytes   UIKit   -[UIWebSelectionAssistant addNonEditableForceTextSelectionGestureRecognizersToView:]
```

### #

I'm sure that the webView, myViewController were delayed, but when pop the myViewController, 4M increased and not release. Please help and thanks.

List item

Comment: I tried to format your code but it's too much effort, please do it yourself

Comment: Any updates? I think this issue is found to be happening in iOS9 only not in iOS8.

Comment: I third this issue. I recently embed a UIWebView and it starts reporting memory leak for the same footprint.

Comment: I am also getting the same leak in my App with Xcode 7, iOS9, where ever I am using UIWebView. Is this is specific to UIWebView? Perhaps an Apple Bug. Not sure how to deal with this.

Comment: Also experiencing the same issue. Did anyone happen to have a fix?

Answer (score 3):

According to [an answer posted here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/24539), there is a workaround that if you set `configuration.selectionGranularity` to `WKSelectionGranularityCharacter`, the leaks stop:

```
let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
config.selectionGranularity = .character //WKSelectionGranularityCharacter
let myWebview = WKWebview(frame: frame, configuration: config)
```

This worked for me, but then, when selecting text, there was no selection rectangle in the webview.  This may or may not be a viable workaround in your case.

**Edit**  I just noticed your question is for UIWebView, not WKWebView.  It doesn't look like you can set this on UIWebView.  I'll leave this answer for now since WKWebView folks googling this memory leak will probably find this thread...

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not fix the issue with WKWebView's... :(

Comment: Maybe there's more factors?  It did when I wrote this, and it seems to be true for others, even now - though I haven't retested in newer iOS versions.